# How to create a new timezone in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, timezone

I want to create a timezone definition for UTC+n without any DST changes for our testing purposes, but haven't figured out how to do it.  I'm using ActiveSupport::TimeZone, but it seems that it has a hard-coded list of time zones which cannot be programmatically extended.

In particular, however I try to create a new timezone, it is always missing DST information.  If I provide an existing timezone as a basis, it ignores the time offset I provided instead.

Below are some attempts I tried to create a timezone in UTC+1:

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone[1].now
 => Tue, 06 Aug 2013 12:39:35 CEST +02:00 
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("UTC", 3600).now
 => Tue, 06 Aug 2013 10:39:40 UTC +00:00 
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("foo", 3600).now
TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier: cannot load such file -- tzinfo/definitions/foo
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("foo", 3600, TZInfo::Timezone.get("UTC")).now
 => Tue, 06 Aug 2013 10:39:48 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby,  but the tzinfo database has such timezones already, so you should be able to use them. They are usually under Etc, so you could try with 'GMT+1' or 'Etc/GMT+1'.

Comment: Have you tried using [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)?

Comment: I noticed that 'Etc/GMT+1' works.  However it's [confusingly named](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29784&group_id=894&atid=3525) so 'Etc/GMT+2' produces the time zone -0200 instead of +0200.  I'd still prefer a cleaner way to create a time zone.